# Why the size not match to each other

Tags: modeling

I have a curve of 100x100cm. And added a default plane of 100x100cm. The plane and the curve not match as per the size. The curve is a dxf file imported in Blender. Scale rotation are 1 & 0. yet the size not match with each other. Any suggestion. Thanks

[image]

**Red mark is the curve so tinny.** Below is the plane 100x100 cam

[image]

**Tinny curve dxf design**

[image]

Comment: The curve is not tiny, it's way up in the sky

Comment: @Gorgious its just approx 35cm from the origin.

Comment: The origin, yes, but if you go into Edit mode you'll see the Z coordinates of the curve points are very high

Comment: @Gorgious thanks got it